# How to mention file name in nox + pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, nox

My nox function looks something like this

```
@nox.session(python=["3.7", "3.8", "3.9"])
def test(session: nox.Session) -> None:
    """Run unit tests."""
    session.install("-e", ".[all]")
    session.install("-e", ".[tests]")
    print (session.posargs)
    session.run("pytest", *session.posargs)
```

How to update the above function to run tests of specific files or file patterns like `tests/*/test_postgres_*.py`

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a quick example that demonstrates how to use arguments to run tests against a particular file:

```
@nox.session
def test(session):
    session.install('pytest')

    if session.posargs:
        test_files = session.posargs
    else:
        test_files = ['test_a.py', 'test_b.py']

    session.run('pytest', *test_files)
```

you run:

```
nox -- test_c.py
```

Then nox will run:

```
pytest test_c.py
```

[nox posargs](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/config.html?highlight=posargs#passing-arguments-into-sessions)